# HTTPS page with HTTP API content: best practices

Tags: api, security, https

I have an HTTPS site that uses the Google Books API to generate a page of book images. However, the book cover images from Google Books are only available via HTTP, which results in mixed content warnings for any page on my site that displays the books.

What is the recommended practice in this scenario? As I see it, I have three options:

1. Leave it as. My page will technically be insecure for end users and will display mixed content warnings.
2. Cache the images on my server and display the local copy to users. This will remove the mixed content warning, but it seems that in this case my server is vulnerable to MITM attacks and such because it is downloading content over HTTP. Doesn't sound appealing.
3. Stop using the API and scrap the whole feature from the website. Obviously not an appealing choice.

None of these looks good. Is there some magic-bullet solution that I just don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for option 2 as being the most transparent. Actually you don't need a cache (if you don't want it) but just a proxy that will receive HTTPS requests, send HTTP request and pass the received data back to the HTTPS client.

Comment: That would be nice and easy. But that seems to be pretty non-transparent. It gives the end user the impression that they are viewing a secure page when, in fact, they are seeing insecure content that is masked behind a proxy. It seems to still have the same security issues as #1.

Comment: @penco it's up to you to decide, but with option 1 you will annoy people all the time. If you want to be sincere, inform people by presenting them some banner or an alert when they visit a page for the first time.

Comment: They are viewing a secure page. All HTTPS does is ensure the connection between their browser and your server is encrypted - it does not guarantee encryption beyond that (e.g. see Gmail). IMO option 1 isn't good as if they agree to view mixed content they can no longer ensure that their connection to your server is encrypted (they no longer know if there's any other HTTP only content apart from the book cover image).

Comment: Okay, I will go with a proxy, then.